# how many key-value can hashslot save in redis cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

background understanding：in Redis cluster mode, every key-value will be distributed to a steady hashslot by CRC16(key) mod 16384.

redis cluster contains 16384 slots, my quetions is: in redis cluster mode, we just can save 16384 key-value(i think it is impossible, but i don't known why)? or one slot mappings many key-value, the algorithms before is just calculate the specific slot?

thank you for answerring sinserely.

Comment: The algorithm is used for finding the slot for a given key. A slot can contains many keys.

Answer (score 1):

A Slot can have multiple keys value the above algorithm just specifies the slot where the data needs to be stored or in which slot and depending on the number of shards the slots are distributed and the data in saved in one of them and automatically deleted when the ttl is over.